# CATiledLayer drawing delay

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iphone app.
It has following page structure, 
1.List of game levels in a UITableView
2.Game page

I use "UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight" between pages

Game page has 3 views, One is a scrollView in that my game grid is drawn.
Game grid is a sub class of UIView ,that added to Scrollview.
To support zooming i use CATiledLayer to draw the grid(20*20).

MY problem is GameGrid shows white or last played puzzles grid contents for a few seconds and then refresh(flashing) to the new content.

My GameGrid class as follows

`

```
 @implementation GameGrid

+(Class)layerClass
{    
 return [CATiledLayer class];
}

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {   
        if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
           CATiledLayer *tempTiledLayer = (CATiledLayer*)self.layer;
           tempTiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 5;
           tempTiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 2;        
              self.opaque=YES;  
           }
             return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
 //empty
}

-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
 // here i am drawing grid
// filling rect
 // lines
// string etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much supposed to happen, it's doing (some of) the drawing in a thread.

It's been a while since I worked on this, but I used

```
@interface FastCATiledLayer : CATiledLayer
@end

@implementation FastCATiledLayer

+(CFTimeInterval)fadeDuration
{
    return 0.0;     // Normally it’s 0.25
}

@end
```

because I didn't like the forced initial delay. That may help.